# Docker - ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement lgpio==0.1.0.0

Tags: python-3.x, docker, pip, gpio, raspberry-pi4

While running `docker-compose up` I got an error connected with Python library version.

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement lgpio==0.1.0.0 (from versions: 0.0.0.2)
```

While installing this lib in the newest version (0.1.0.1) is possible on local Python 3.10.4.

My `Dockerfile` is:

```
FROM python:3.10.4
WORKDIR /Gpio_App
COPY ./requirements.txt /Gpio_App/requirements.txt
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
COPY ./app /Gpio_App/app
CMD ["uvicorn", "app.main:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "8000"]
```

and my `requirements.txt` looks like that:

```
fastapi>=0.68.0,<0.69.0
uvicorn>=0.15.0,<0.16.0
lgpio>=0.1.0.0,<=0.1.0.1
```

Comment: which version of python do you use locally ?

Comment: Python 3.10.4 on Ubuntu 22.04 x64

Comment: well, the version in your dockerfile is 3.8 so the version of the package you're asking for might not be available on a python version prior to 3.10

Comment: The same error with python:3.10.4 in Dockerfile

Answer (score 0):

`lgpio` 0.1.0.0 [provides](https://pypi.org/project/lgpio/0.1.0.0/#files) **eggs** for Python 2.7 and 3.8, Linux 64 bit. Nothing else, not even source code. This is especially bad because `pip` lost ability to install eggs long ago; it's an outdated package format.

Release 0.0.0.2 [provides](https://pypi.org/project/lgpio/0.0.0.2/#files) a universal Python 3 **wheel** and a source distribution.

At PyPI there is a download link http://abyz.me.uk/lg/lg.zip. The zip currently contains version 0.2.0.0. But it requires compilation.

Comment: Any idea to install egg with docker?

Comment: A Python egg is a zip file that can be unpacked with `unzip`. Please be careful with shared libraries (`*.so`) compiled for different versions of Python. They could easily crash interpreter.

Comment: One more question. Why ```pip3 install lgpio==0.1.0.1``` on local python is working and in ```Dockerfile``` not?

Comment: No idea. I cannot make `pip3 install lgpio==0.1.0.1` to work locally. Are you sure the version is really **0.1.0.1**? If you have an error message from Docker my advice is to ask a separate question.

Comment: What is your local pip version? `pip3 --version`?

Comment: Local: pip 22.0.2 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip (python 3.10). How to check the version of pip used inside Docker container?